# Can i build a real commercial web application using Microsoft visual web developer 2010 express

Tags: sql-server-2008, asp.net-mvc-3

I have downloaded the free Microsoft visual web developer 2010 express which comes also with MS sql server express database to build an MVC 3 web application.
I can build the real web application with a database for free; but i have the following questions:-

1. can i build a real commercial web application using these free tools?
2. what are the limitations of using Microsoft sql server express database comparing to using Microsoft sql server enterprise   edition?
   BR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can build a fully functional application with the express tool suite, however your productivity won't be as great as that of a full visual studio environment.

For example you can't use add in's like resharper and your debugging abilities are limited. With sql express you are again limited with the toolset you have available to you, not to mention a maximum database size restriction.

Comment: I would be more concerned about scalability issues (CPU, RAM, database size to name a few) as opposed to developer productivity. The question wasn't about the Express version of the development environment, but rather the Express version of the database engine. You can use *either* the full Visual Studio experience or the Expres version, to develop against *either* the Express version of SQL Server or higher SKUs (in fact many SKUs).

Comment: do u mean that there is limitation regarding the database size in sql server express ?

Comment: @johnG yes, there is a 10 GB limit for SQL Server Express 2008

Comment: then this means i can get sql server enterprise edition (which of course does not have any limitation in the size) and to build my asp.net mvc3 web application against this enterprise sql server using the free Microsoft visual web developer 2010 express ? OR in this case i still have some limitations ?